# Music Theory and Lead Guitar

Tags: theory

Why do the same intervals sound less resolved on different areas of the fretboard? Do consonant intervals mean the note resolves? Why then if a major or minor 2nd sounds like the note resolves, especially in the solo in American Woman by the Guess Who and in the major scale when the 7th resolves into the root? Finally how do you find out which note resolves to which?

Comment: Welcome! There are some intriguing questions here. A couple of things, though: 1) Stack Exchange works best when each posting focuses on a single question. Sounds like most of this one focuses on "what is resolving, anyway, and how does it work?" I'd suggest removing the parts about "why does it sound different in a different register or timbre" and making that its own question. 2) We might use the words "interval" and "resolve" in a different way. Can you edit to make it clearer how you're thinking of it? I.e. is an interval two notes played one after the other, or simultaneously?

Comment: There are no consonant intervals ... there are 'more consonant' and 'less consonant' intervals relative to each other. For example, a V note resolves to a I note because it's closer to I as a function of fifths.

This is why the pattern of 4-1-5-2-6-3-7, the pattern of the position of a note as you traverse keys, is also telling you about dissonance.

The G is one position away from C (the 5 and 1) ... which is a more consonant interval than D to C ... the D being the 2, another fifth away.

Comment: Please clarify, you're saying the note that is closest to the note being played is the note that it resolves to?

Comment: Also please explain to me more about the 4-1-5-2-6-3-7 means