# Music Theory and Intervals

Tags: intervals

Why do the same intervals sound less resolved on different areas of the fretboard?

Comment: Welcome back! Looks like you took my advice to split your [earlier question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/119070/music-theory-and-lead-guitar) up; thanks! The problem now is that, whatever you mean by "resolved," is probably not the meaning we're working with. In music theory, [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(music)) means handling a dissonance, which means moving from one chord to another. Can you edit this question to explain more about how you're thinking about it?

Comment: You need a more appropriate word than *resolved*.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you’re talking about an instrument with straight frets like a guitar. Basically the fretposition is never perfect. Slight differences between the strings (thickness, tension, action) imply that pressing the string will affect the pitch differently, which means that each string would require unique fret positions. This means that the instrument has questionable intonation depending on the fret position, which also means that intervals will be more or less in tune depending on the position on the fretboard.